# goroutine not returning memory to OS

Tags: go, garbage-collection, containers, prometheus

I want to make sure my pod doesn't get restarted when out of memory. Now I see that container has low heapMem usage but SysMem usage has increased to 4Gb and doesn't recede with heapMem. I believe GC should have returned this to OS.

[image]

Prometheus stats used to monitor `go_memstats_alloc_bytes` and `go_memstats_sys_bytes`. I also see `go_memstats_gc_cpu_fraction` doesn't increase overtime.

Am I missing something? Is there a possible mem leak?

Comment: First, the garbage collector's job is to reclaim garbage and reuse memory, it does not release anything back to the OS. The `MemStat.Sys` field is documented as `[measuring] the virtual address space reserved by the Go runtime [...] It's likely that not all of the virtual address space is backed by physical memory at any given moment`. The graph tells us nothing except that it looks like you have bursts of activity that may use all your memory.

Comment: You can try to set madvdontneed=1 (details: https://golang.org/doc/go1.12#runtime). Basically in Linux golang is using madvfree to release memory back to OS which most of the time will be ignored by OS, unless OS is under memory pressure. And you can also try go 1.13, which should be more aggressive in returning memory back to OS: https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#runtime

Comment: do you find what is problem here, I see my app in container go_memstats_sys_bytes  alway increase and not down too

Answer (score 3):

It does not look like a memory leak from the graph, just a temporary use of more memory.  Note that after a GC the released memory won't be returned to the OS (immediately) in case it is needed again.  If you had a single temporary spike in memory use then it will be returned to the OS over time.

In some systems it may only be made available to the OS which may not accept it unless it's needed elsewhere.  (This was pointed out in the comments but I did not want to get into too much detail, to avoid confusion.)

You can force freed memory to be returned immediately using `debug.FreeOSMemory()`.